# <ul> width by widest <li>, centered in <div>

Tags: css

Okay, I just can't figure this out. I have a fixed width div which is supposed to hold a list of elements (icon, name, price, stuff like that). The `li` contents should be aligned to the left but the whole list to the center.

This is basically my idea:

[image: sketch]

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4k1Lt4s/) without my pathetic attempts to solve this via inline-block.

```
    <div class="wrap">
<ul>
    <li><span class="icon">x</span>
        <span class="name">lorem ipsum</span>  <span class="price">$1,000</span>
        <span class="info">New York City</span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="icon">x</span>
        <span class="name">dolor sit amet inscipiciur edit vole</span>  <span class="price">$3,000</span>
        <span class="info">Boston</span>

    </li>
    <li><span class="icon">x</span>
        <span class="name">syra nasum foedum habet</span>
        <span class="price">$900</span>
        <span class="info">San Francisco</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

```
        .wrap {
    width:300px;
    background:lightgrey;
    font:sans-serif
}
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
ul {
    border:1px solid blue
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    height:40px;
    margin-bottom:20px
}
.icon {
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-right:8px;
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    background:grey
}
.name {
    display:block;
    height:50%;
    background:#aaaaaa
}
.price {
    border:1px solid #4e4e4e;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:0 3px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px
}
.info {
    background:#eeeeee
}
```

Can I achieve this?

(Normally, the `ul` will be 100% width and when set to `display:inline-block`, the contents of the individual `li`s will become misaligned.)

Comment: what exactly is the question???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w4k1Lt4s/2/?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `text-align:center;` for `.wrap` and `display:inline-block; text-align:left;` for `<ul>`:

.wrap {text-align:center;}

```
ul {
    border:1px solid blue;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sqzeodfh/)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not solve the `ul` width set by widest `li`. See [here](http://jab.novotny.je/home2/#stackoverflow) ("Slevy v App Storu"). The longest description gets wrapped to another line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just "center" the whole `<ul>` (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w4k1Lt4s/3/)

then just add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `wrap` class...

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple. If you add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.wrap`, it should center the div which contains your list. The first parameter `0` sets the margin for the top and bottom of the element and can be whatever you want, like `10px`, but having `auto` as the second parameter automatically sets the margin to the same amount on both the left and right sides.

i.e.

```
.wrap {
width:300px;
background:lightgrey;
font:sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```